# Data attribute undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have a textbox and a checkbox:

```
<input type="text" id="tb1" onFocus="CheckboxDisable('cb1');" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" data-ieflub=""/>
```

When the textbox comes into focus, I would like to disable the checkbox and set the data attribute ieflub to a value. My code is the following:

```
function CheckboxDisable(id){
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;

    $('#id').attr('ieflub', 'yes');
}
```

As you can see, quite simple. Except, it doesn't work.

I traced through this, using Firebug and see that `$('#id').data('data-ieflub');` is undefined inside the CheckboxDisable function.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing some undeclared (looks like) variable `cb1`, while based on how you are using it in `CheckboxDisable` function, you want to pass the string `cb1`:

```
<input type="text" id="tb1" onFocus="CheckboxDisable('cb1');" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" data-ieflub=""/>
```

Also in the function you need to construct selector with variable:

```
function CheckboxDisable(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
    $('#' + id).data('ieflub', 'yes');
}
```

Note, that there is a convenient method to deal with data-attributes `$.fn.data`. Of course you could also go with `attr` method, but in this case you should have used full attribute name `.attr('data-ieflub', 'yes')`. With `data` method, prefix data- should be dropped.

Finally, it makes sense to use jQuery fully and change from

```
document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
```

to `$()` method. The final function after additional optimization will become:

```
function CheckboxDisable(id) {
    $('#' + id).prop('disabled', true).data('ieflub', 'yes');
}
```

New methods used:

- [`$.fn.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to get/set DOM element properties, like disabled, checked, etc.
- [`$.fn.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to get/set data properties, read data-attributes.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect the actual 'cb1' string being passed.

Comment: I cannot vote you up more than once. I just commented `$('#' + id).prop("disabled",true).data("ieflub","yes")`  and you added it while I commented

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, I was getting there, after explaining initial approach problems. Thank you!

Comment: And now add the whole thing to the head and disable the next sibling instead of a named thing :)

Comment: yes, and make use of `.on('focus', function() {})` instead of `onFocus=` inline. Well there are still things that could be improved, definitely.

Comment: That's what I meant by adding it to the head (unobtrusively) :)

Answer (score 0):

The `'#id'` in `$('#id').attr('ieflub', 'yes');` is an ordinary string - it isn't getting replaced by `'#cb1'` as you might like. Try `$('#' + id).attr('ieflub', 'yes');` instead.

There's also a problem in your html - replace `onFocus="CheckboxDisable(cb1);"` with `onFocus="CheckboxDisable('cb1');"` - you want to pass the string of the id, not a variable called `cb1`.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I tried it and it actually breaks the javascript.

Comment: Which of the two suggestions? If you pass `cb1`, `cb1` will be an undefined variable. If you pass `'cb1'`, the argument passed into the function will be the string `'cb1'`.

Comment: My actual code was always correct. I updated the Question accordingly with the passed string, 'cb1', rather than the undefined object, cb1. I apologize for my mistake in typing it out.

Comment: My actual code was always correct. I updated the Question accordingly with the passed string, 'cb1', rather than the undefined object, cb1. I apologize for my mistake in typing it out.

Comment: But, where I was saying the JQuery breaks is with the $('#' + id). This returns as 'undefined' every time I run it.

Comment: `$('#' + id)` returns as undefined? Or `'#' + id` returns as undefined?

Comment: $('#' + id) returns as Object[]. $('#' + id).data('ieflub'); returns as undefined.

Comment: If you use `.attr('ieflub')` you're setting the `ieflub` attribute, not the `data-ieflub` attribute. If you use `.data` both times (and leave off the `data-` prefix), or use `attr` both times (and include the `data-` prefix), you should be fine.